# How to get the "end" of the request on Express / Sails?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I want to minify the HTML on the views, so I need to inject a function (middleware) that gets the request content and parse to minify the html / ejs.

I was trying this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667227/how-to-sailsjs-minify-html-views-with-ejs

But it was closed, I don't know why, now I'm trying this code below, but the console doesn't show the logs, so the events are not being called. Anyone knows how to do this?

```
module.exports = {

    http: {
        customMiddleware: function (app) {
            app.use(function(req,res, next) {
              res.on('data', function(chunk){
                console.log("INFO: "+chunk);
                response += chunk;
              });

              res.on('end', function(){
                console.log("End received!");
              });

              res.on('close', function(){
                console.log("Close received!");
              });

              next();

            });

        }
    }

};
```